# How to create a Pre-Loading/ Splash Screen in Nuxt.js before the app starts?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, splash-screen, nuxtjs

I have tried to add a loader as shown in the nuxt.js documentation in between the routes but its not work. But I'm not able to add a splash screen before the app starts.

Code snippet in my **components/loading.vue**

```
<template>
  <div v-if="loading" class="loading-page">
    <p>Loading...</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    loading: false
  }),
  methods: {
    start(){
      this.loading = true
    },
    finish(){
      this.loading = false
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In **nuxt.js.config**

```
export default {
...

loading: '~/components/loading.vue'
...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, you can't use a Vue component as a loading indicator for your your Nuxt app.
You will have to create an HTML document instead. This HTML document does not have to have an `<html>`, `<head>` or `<body>`. It just has to be the splash screen you want to show.

**Here's how I did it:**

1. Create an html document `~/assets/loading.html`
2. Add the following to `nuxt.config.js` file.

```js
loadingIndicator: {
  name: '~/assets/loading.html'
}
```

3. Save and reload your page, you should now have a custom loading indicator / splash screen.

**Example HTML file:**
Here's a very simple file to show a splash screen image, when loading a nuxt app.

```html
<div style="height: 100vh; width: 100vw; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; flex-direction: column; background-color: #004066; margin-left: -8px; margin-top: -8px; overflow: hidden;">
  <img width="90%" src="<%= options.img %>">
</div>
```

**NOTE:**
Pay attention to `<%= options.img %>`. I'm making use of options, which can be defined in the `nuxt.config.js` simply by adding more keys to `loadingIndicator`, an example can be seen below.

```js
loadingIndicator: {
  name: '~/assets/loading.html',
  img: '/loading.gif'
}
```

**NOTE 2:**
When accessing assets such as images in the loading indicator, you will have to put them in the `/static` folder.

Documentation: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/loading#custom-indicators
Official examples: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/packages/vue-app/template/views/loading

Comment: Doesn't seem to work in 2024 (Nuxt ver 3.8). Please post an update if available.